# Django : improve performance on multiple uploads

Tags: python, django, file

I am working on a API to upload files from client to server. 
Each file from the client side need to be copied to server side.

```
<input type="file" id="id_docfile" name="docfile" multiple>
```

Is there a better way to upload files so that the uploading time can be reduced ?  Can I upload files in parallel ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some options you might want to try:

1) There are a few easy-to-use Javascript plugins which have this feature. [Here is one example](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone).

2) Using Amazon S3 to store your files instead of storing them in your server. You can then [check this post](https://dzone.com/articles/amazon-s3-parallel-multipart) to learn how to upload multiple files fastly.